# Python keyboard.add_hotkey(): как создать допущение в бинде?

Tags: python, клавиатура, binding

Работаю с библиотекой keyboard. В программе нужно забиньдить клавишу space + любое сочетание. Долго искал информацию на это тему так и не нашел. Может кто-то знает решения?

```
from tkinter import *
import keyboard

def stuff():
    keyboard.send("space")

root = Tk()
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.geometry('300x400')

keyboard.add_hotkey('space', stuff)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать

```
key = keyboard.read_hotkey()
```

после чего сохранить сочетание как

```
keyboard.add_hotkey(f'space+{key}', stuff)
```

Или можно сразу нажать 2 (или больше) кнопки, тогда в `key` будет записано `'key+key2'`, где `key1`, `key2` и т.д. - нажатые кнопки

---

Если вам нужно вообще любое сочетание, то можно попробовать так:

```
import keyboard
from threading import Thread

def check_hotkey():
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('space') and len(keyboard._pressed_events) > 1:
            print('Нажато сочетание клавиш с пробелом')


Thread(target = check_hotkey).start()
```

Здесь мы проверяем, чтобы был нажат пробел, и при этом кол-во нажатых клавиш было больше 1. Запуск в отдельном потоке, так как у вас вроде бы графический интерфейс, а `while True` просто не даст ему работать в основном потоке.

Разумеется, есть более удачные способы реализации, чтобы без отдельного потока.

Comment: Да, я тоже так пытался, но это все равно создает условия нажатий определенных клавиш. Просто если забиньдить просто пробел или определенное сочетание клавиш, то при случайном нажатии другой кнопки, бинд не сработает.

Comment: @ozyhonor дополнил ответ

Comment: Получилось сделать?